# How to get the same time in the first day of the week in Carbon?

Tags: php-carbon

For example, I tried

```
Carbon::parse('2018-06-15 12:34:00')->startOfWeek();
```

and

```
Carbon::parse('2018-06-15 12:34:00')->modify('last Monday');
```

They all return "2018-06-11 00:00:00"

Is there any way to return "2018-06-11 12:34:00"?

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
$date = '2018-06-15 12:34:00';
$carbon = Carbon::parse($date);
$hour = $carbon->format('H:i:s');
$start_of_week = $carbon->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hour;
dd($start_of_week);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I end up with manually subtracting the weekdays,

```
Carbon::parse($dateTime)->subDays($randomDateTime->isoWeekday());
```